# Can you draft a question before making it public?

Tags: support, editor, draft

Can you draft a question before making it public for everyone on Stack Overflow? A lot of times, when the question gets laid out in that format it helps you think, and avoid pushing out something silly like a typo or code that isn't up to date with what you are currently working on.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? You can already preview it below the editor.

Comment: You can have draft Q&A in the StackExchange mobile app (on iOS); not sure about android or the newer SO mobile app.  For the site, how about you just leave the tab open in the background where you started typing the Q?

Comment: Essentially you're asking here to make it so posting a question requires two clicks, right? Put a little extra moment of contemplation in between.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can draft a post before you actually publish it.  According to this [MSE answer about drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238), the Stack Overflow editor saves a single draft for questions and another one for answers at a profile level.  The text in the editor will be periodically saved (every 45 seconds).  Drafts last for up to 7 days, or until you manually post or discard them.  If you are using drafts to gather your thoughts and proofread your work, the 7 day limit shouldn't be an issue.

I don't know of any way to manually save the draft on the site itself, but you could always save the raw markdown elsewhere.  Then just copy-paste.